# How to get a True or False output for MVC3 Model Validation

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc-3

I'm using a form to post information and my model has validation built into it. I know that I can validate the fields by using Either of the following:

```
@Html.ValidationSummary() //To validate all fields

@Html.ValidationMessageFor(x => x.FirstName) //To validate single field
```

Both of these methods just return a HTML list(For ValidationSummary) or a span (ValidateionMessageFor).

What I would like to do is just get a true or false statement if the field is valid or not (Or null if nothing) so that I can do some custom styling to the box that contains the input, or even the label for it.

Does anyone know if there is such a code that will do this, like `@Html.IsValid(x => x.FirstName)`

Here is my Model and View. The model is pulling through and validating correctly, it is just a question of whether or not I can get a Boolean value instead of HTML string.

**MODEL:**

```
using System.ComponentModel.DataAnnotations;

namespace X.Web.Helpers
{
    public class RequestSamplesModel
    {
        [Required]
        public string FirstName { get; set; }
        [Required]
        public string LastName { get; set; }

        public string Email { get; set; }
        [Required]
        public string Line1 { get; set; }
        [Required]
        public string Line2 { get; set; }
        [Required]
        public string City { get; set; }
        [Required]
        public string Postcode { get; set; }
        [Required]
        public string Country { get; set; }
    }
}
```

**VIEW:**

```
@{
    Layout = "~/Views/Shared/_PlainLayout.cshtml";
}
@using X.Web.Helpers
@model RequestSamplesModel

<form action="/Site/RequestSamples" method="POST">
    <div class="form-item">
        <span>First Name:</span>@Html.TextBoxFor(x => x.FirstName)</div>
    <div class="form-item">
        <span>Last Name:</span>@Html.TextBoxFor(x => x.LastName)</div>
    <div class="form-item">
        <span>Email:</span>@Html.TextBoxFor(x => x.Email)</div>
    <div class="form-item">
        <span>Address 1:</span>@Html.TextBoxFor(x => x.Line1)</div>
    <div class="form-item">
        <span>Address 2:</span>@Html.TextBoxFor(x => x.Line2)</div>
    <div class="form-item">
        <span>City:</span>@Html.TextBoxFor(x => x.City)</div>
    <div class="form-item">
        <span>Postcode:</span>@Html.TextBoxFor(x => x.Postcode)</div>
    <div class="form-item">
        <span>Country:</span>@Html.TextBoxFor(x => x.Country)</div>
    <div class="form-item">
        <input class="submit-button" type="image" src="/_content/images/email-submit.gif" /></div>
</form>
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> Does anyone know if there is such a code that will do this, like
>   @Html.IsValid(x => x.FirstName)

No, there isn't such code built-in. But it would be trivial to write one so that now there is:

```
public static class HtmlExtensions
{
    public static bool IsValid<TModel, TProperty>(
        this HtmlHelper<TModel> htmlHelper, 
        Expression<Func<TModel, TProperty>> expression
    )
    {
        var modelState = htmlHelper.ViewData.ModelState;
        var name = ExpressionHelper.GetExpressionText(expression);
        var key = htmlHelper.ViewContext.ViewData.TemplateInfo.GetFullHtmlFieldName(name);
        ModelState value;
        return !modelState.TryGetValue(key, out value) || 
               value.Errors.Count == 0;
    }
}
```

Now in your views simply bring the extension method into scope and:

```
@if (Html.IsValid(x => x.FirstName))
{
    @:<div>Super, the first name is valid</div>
}
```

Comment: That's awesome, thanks a bunch. Will be using this quite a bit. Shame there isn't already that kind of function built into it :/

Comment: @JakeJ, please read the following blog post to understand why there are some features that you might want seeing built-in but they aren't: http://blogs.msdn.com/b/ericlippert/archive/2003/10/28/53298.aspx

Comment: Thanks for that, that's actually a very interesting article. Although this is a little more than a one-off thing that will be used, it is something that I have always been wondering and wanting to use but having to make workarounds instead as I work with forms quite a lot. But either way, this snippet will save me a bunch of time in the future, thanks again.